# SwiftUI - Update data on Firebase's Realtime database

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have successfully displayed the data to the UI, but I want the user to be able to update my data again when tapping the "Save" button . Hope you can help me!

Profile

```
I have successfully displayed the data to the UI, but I want the user to be able to update my data again when tapping the "Save" button . Hope you can help me!
```

Comment: At which line are you pressing the Save button?

Comment: @ElTomato I am just successfully rendering the UI. I have not implemented Save button

Comment: show us a complete example of the code you are using, including where you want to update your data in your UI and any relevant UI context.

Comment: @workingdog I have updated my code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. This is just one approach, by
passing the `profileViewModel` to `EditProfile`:

```
class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user = Profile(id: "", image: "", birthDay: "", role: [], gender: "", name: "")
    private var ref: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference()

    func fetchData(userId: String? = nil) {
        // 8hOqqnFlfGZTj1u5tCkTdxAED2I3
        ref.child("users").child(userId ?? "default").observe(.value) { [weak self] (snapshot) in
            guard let self = self,
                  let value = snapshot.value else { return }
            do {
                print("user: \(value)")
                self.user = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(Profile.self, from: value)
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveUser() {
        // save the user using your ref DatabaseReference
        // using setValue, or updateChildValues 
        // see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write
    }
}

struct EditProfile: View {
    @ObservedObject var profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel  // <--- here
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(profileViewModel.user.name)  // <--- you probably meant TextField
                .font(.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: 15))
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            Text("\(profileViewModel.user.birthDay)!")
                .font(.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: 22))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            Text("\(profileViewModel.user.gender)")
                .font(.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: 22))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            Text(profileViewModel.user.role.first ?? "")
                .font(.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: 22))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
           
       Button(action: {
            // save the profileViewModel.user to database
            profileViewModel.saveUser()  // <--- here
            }) {
                Text("Save")
            }

        }
        .padding()
    }
}
struct CategoriesView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = SectionViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var loginViewModel : LoginViewModel
    @StateObject var profileViewModel = ProfileViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing:0) {
                    EditProfile(profileViewModel: profileViewModel)  // <--- here
                        .padding()
                        .padding(.bottom,-10)
                 }
             }
          .onAppear() {
                self.viewModel.fetchData()
                profileViewModel.fetchData(userId: loginViewModel.session?.uid)
            }
        }
}
```

EDIT1: regarding the updated code.

In your new code, in `ProfileHost` you are not passing ProfileViewModel.
Use:

```
NavigationLink(destination: ProfileEditor(profileViewModel: viewModel)) {
     ProfileRow(profileSetting: profile)
}
```

And in `ProfileEditor` replace `profile` with `profileViewModel.user`
You will probably need to adjust `profileItem` and put it in a `.onAppear {...}` . Something like this:

```
struct ProfileEditor: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @ObservedObject var profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel
    
    let profileLabel: [String] = ["Name", "Account", "Gender", "Role", "Email"]
    @State var profileItem: [String] = []
    @State var profileEditorRow: [ProfileEditorItem] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(profileEditorRow) { editor in
                if editor.id == 5 {
                    ProfileEditorRow(editor: editor, showLastLine: true)
                } else {
                    ProfileEditorRow(editor: editor, showLastLine: false)
                }
            }
            Button("Save") {
                profileViewModel.updateData(userId: loginViewModel.session?.uid)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            profileItem = [profileViewModel.user.name,
                           profileViewModel.user.birthDay,
                           profileViewModel.user.gender,
                           profileViewModel.user.role.first ?? "",
                           profileViewModel.user.birthDay]

            for n in 1...5 {
                profileEditorRow.append(ProfileEditorItem(id: n, label: profileLabel[n-1], item: profileItem[n-1]))
            } 
        }
    }
    
}
```

EDIT2: update func

```
func updateData() {
    ref.("users").child(user.id).updateChildValues([
        "name": user.name,
        "birthDay": user.birthDay,
        "gender": user.gender,
        "role": user.role.first ?? ""])
}
```

and use this in `ProfileEditor` :

```
        Button("Save") {
             profileViewModel.updateData()
         }
```

Comment: I followed you but it doesn't work

Comment: what exactly does not work? Do you get some errors? I suspect the code you are using is not what you are showing us, for example, `EditProfile` does not edit anything. It's best if you can edit your question and show exactly what code you are using.

Comment: Because it divides many levels, I want to summarize you.                                               
I have updated all my current code above

Comment: I've updated my answer reflecting the new code you show.

Comment: Can you edit it in my code?

Comment: try my updated answer.

Comment: It already shows the UI. But when I click the Save button, it crashes. Can you see my Updatedate section?

Comment: does it crash when you use my `ProfileEditor` or you original code? Your code will crash because you do not pass the `profileViewModel`.

Comment: My original code also shows the UI. Could it be wrong in the UpdateData func. ?

Comment: Can you see the updateData function in my ProfileViewModel class.

Comment: in `ProfileHost` you are not passing `ProfileViewModel`, that is why it crashes. Update the code and show what error you get.

Comment: I updated the code and took a picture of the error above

Comment: Hope you can help me, because i have to finish it tomorrow

Comment: I don't have Firebase realtime db setup, so I can only guess.
See my updated answer.

Comment: It doesn't move to func updateData

Comment: last try. See my updated answer.

Comment: It moves into func updateData, but it doesn't update the value

Comment: I suggest you re-think your code structure. At the moment, it's not very good. 
You need to use `ProfileViewModel` and in particular `user` directly as one source of truth, no intermediate `profileItem`, no `ProfileEditorItem` for the `ProfileEditorRow`.
 Use `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject` to share the state of the model.
Ultimately, you need to pass `ProfileViewModel` to your `ProfileEditorRow` 
for your editing to be captured.
Regarding your latest problem, ask yourself what is the `user` you want to update,
and then search for how to do it online.

Comment: I'm sure you will get your assignment done. If my answers gave you some help, please mark it accordingly. Good luck.